# How to configure HAproxy to a different backend based on path?

Tags: reverse-proxy, load-balancing, haproxy, backend

The problem is that, I have haproxy configured for multiple domains with backends respectively. The intended behaviour is to redirect a specific request such as `myfirstdomain.com/alerts` to `backend2` and the already configured backend `myfirstdomain.com` still configured to provide for `backend1`.

**Current haproxy.cfg**

```
frontend https_443_frontend
  bind *:80
  bind *:443 ssl crt build_rupid_in.pem crt code_rupid_in.pem crt artifacts_rupid_in.pem crt prodmon_rupid_in.pem crt prodmondb_rupid_in.pem

  acl ACL_backend0 hdr(host) -i myzerodomain.com
  use_backend backend_backend0 if ACL_backend0

  acl ACL_backend1 hdr(host) -i myfirstdomain.com
  use_backend backend_backend1 if ACL_backend1

backend backend_backend0
  mode http
  server app01 127.0.0.1:9909

backend backend_backend1
  mode http
  server app02 127.0.0.1:9990
```

**What i tried**

```
ACL_alerts path -i -m alerts
use_backend backend2 if ACL_backend1 ACL_alerts
backend backend2
  mode http
  server app2 127.0.0.1:9999
```

What else should I change and please help me in understanding how this works. I guess I need to add `http-request replace-path` and `http-response replace-something`. I don't know for sure how this works. Please help me resolve this.

Comment: if i understand correctly how haproxy works, i think nginx would be more suiteable due you can change based on locations. there are like [this similar](https://serverfault.com/questions/605957/haproxy-forward-uri-to-root-of-another-server?rq=1) question that says even too that it seems haproxy may not the right choice

Comment: @djdomi `haproxy` changed a lot in 10 years. `reqrep` isn't supported anymore and replaced by `http-request replace-uri`. This should help https://www.haproxy.com/blog/path-based-routing-with-haproxy

Comment: Alex, I am unaware of the changes because I got stuck on nginx. I believe in your words. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `path_beg` matching. Optionally you can remove `/alerts` part from the URI.

```
frontend https_443_frontend
  bind *:80
  # ssl stuff
 
  use_backend backend2 if { path_beg /alerts/ }
  # fallback for non-matching requests
  default_backend backend1

backend backend1
  mode http
  server app01 127.0.0.1:9909

backend backend2
  mode http
  http-request replace-path /alerts(/)?(.*) /\2
  server app02 127.0.0.1:9990
```